# Como pegar a string do JSon sem saber o que tem nele?

Tags: android, json

Eu uso o jo.getString("nome") para pegar o valor de um arquivo JSon, tem como eu pegar este nome sem ter que colocar o "nome" dentro do getString?

Comment: Qual o contexto da pergunta? qual a linguagem? você pode criar um exemplo **verificável**?

Answer (score -1):

Bom acho que isso não é possível pelo fato do jSON trabalhar com chave e valor ou seja
{"nome":"Alessandro"} para acessar o valor 'Alessandro' você deve acessar pela sua key ou chave que no caso é o "nome" e isso no android você usa o getString("nome") se for uma string que você desejar obter.

Comment: É possível sim.